# How does insert into select work internally in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-insert

Let's consider the following insertion:

```
INSERT INTO SOMETABLE
SELECT * FROM SOMETABLE
WHERE Column > NUMBER
```

Is there a risk that result set of the `SELECT` statement can be changed due to inserting?
In the other words how many times the `SELECT` statement can be calculated by query engine to perform `INSERT INTO SELECT` to the same table?

Assumption: A single thread scenario without concurrent transactions.

Comment: No. An insert is a single ACIDic operation. If it wasn't there would be massive problems with the whole concept of a database. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID

Comment: I think the same but I was surprised when I saw that single row was duplicated several times instead only once. Maybe I had hallucinations I will check again .

Comment: @grabus: Are you using joins? It's handy to comment out the `INSERT` line and run just the `SELECT` portion to troubleshoot queries like this. That way, you can verify that your `SELECT` statement is pulling in the data you expect. I suspect you have a misconfigured join or some bad data. If you expect to be inserting unique records, `DISTINCT` can help with that.

Comment: That was due to bad data in table. I had to have copies before I performed `INSERT INTO SELECT` statement. EOT

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a risk that result set of the SELECT statement can be changed due to inserting?

No. The result set of the `SELECT` statement will not be affected by the `INSERT`. The result of the `SELECT` will be the same as if you ran it by itself.